# How do I sysprep a computer image

Tags: disk-image, sysprep

I'm new to sysprep. I am deploying an image to ~15 computers. I took one of the computers, wiped the hard drive, and created an image. I'm concerned because I'm not sure if I was supposed to sysprep the master image computer before even installing any of the software programs? How about after the image is done and ready to be taken, or how about after the image is already deployed on the new lab computer? Is it important that I do this in a certain order? Thanks.

Comment: We assume you did some research by reading the sysprep documentation? Which OS are you deploying?

Comment: If you want the master image to include those programs, then yes, you would do it after you install those programs.

Comment: Generalizing an environment with Sysprep should be performed immediately prior to capturing an image. Although with that said, there is nothing to stop you from deploying a non-generalized image to the 15 computers and then running Sysprep to generalize each one.

The recommended way is to configure a minimal environment for your base image, Sysprep and capture, then use a deployment solution like MDT to deploy applications and drivers during deployment.

Answer (score 3):

You should only use sysprep immediately before you create a master image. My imaging workflow uses sysprep with a "shutdown after run" flag so I can immediately boot into my imaging media. Essentially you want the image boot after sysprep to be the first boot each of your end-use devices see.

A couple quick notes - be careful with sysprep, it resets your license activation and can only be used a certain number of times with success on a computer before rebuilding it. Also, you may need a sysprep answer file for your environment. This is generated using Microsoft's WAIK toolkit.

Comment: You can use SkipRearm in the answer file to avoid resetting licensing until you actually want to reset licensing and activation. You can generalize an unlimited number of times as long as you are not rearming.